# How to use NVL function as like a if clause, and integrate a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this sql query

```
SELECT cast(dmh.DOC_NO as varchar(35)) AS DOCUMENT_ID, cast(dmh.DOC_TYPE as varchar(30)) AS DOC_TYPE_ID, dmh.CREATE_DATE as DOC_DATE, dmh.LOCATION as LOCATION, dmh.LOC_TYPE as LOC_TYPE, 'DOC_MERCH' as DOC_SOURCE, 
          (SELECT lcompany_fiscal_num
           FROM (SELECT lcompany_fiscal_num
                 FROM NB_IM_LOC_RIM_START locr, NB_LEGAL_COMPANY legalc
                    WHERE locr.LOC_TYPE = dmh.LOC_TYPE
                        AND locr.LOCATION = dmh.LOCATION
                        AND locr.LOC_START_DATE <= dmh.CREATE_DATE
                        AND legalc.LCOMPANY_CODE = locr.COMPANY
                        ORDER BY locr.LOC_START_DATE desc)
                        WHERE rownum = 1) as COMPANY_ID, 'N' as IS_PRINTED, 'N' as IS_MIGRATED
    FROM NB_DOC_MERCH_HEADER dmh
    WHERE dmh.DOC_TYPE IN ('VFT','NDB','VND','CVFT','VTD','VNC','NCI','NNC','CVNC', 'VFI')
          AND dmh.CREATE_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(get_vdate, - (12 * 10)) and get_vdate
          AND dmh.DOCUMENT_ID_SMIS is null;
```

This query returns me this type of results:

| DOCUMENT_ID | DOC_TYPE_ID | DOC_DATE | LOCATION | LOC_TYPE | DOC_SOURCE | COMPANY_ID | IS_PRINTED | IS_MIGRATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1600401 | NDB | 11.11.25 | 16 | S | DOC_MERCH | (null) | N | N |
| 1600401 | NDB | 11.11.25 | 160 | W | DOC_MERCH | (null) | N | N |

As you can see company_id in some cases are null, and i don't want that to happen

What i want to do is: when attrib LOC_TYPE = 'S' i want to do one query and when LOC_TYPE = 'W' i want to do another query, in order to solve the null question.

Is that possible to do with the NVL function? If so, how can i integrate that in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main `select` clause:

```
select cast(...) as document_id, cast(...) as document_type_id, ...
```

When you come to `company_id`, instead of the scalar subquery you have now, write the following `case` expression:

```
select cast(...) as document_id, cast(...) as document_type_id, ...
...
, case loc_type when 'S' then (the scalar subquery for that case)
                when 'W' then (the scalar subquery for that case)
  end as company_id,
....
```

You may have more cases for `loc_type` (use in the same manner), and you can also have a "default" case preceded by the `else` keyword. Note the `end` keyword before the column name (alias); it is part of the `case` expression syntax, and it is mandatory.

I don't see a need for `nvl` since you said you need one thing for case 'S' and another thing for case 'W'. That's not how `nvl` works - you would use that if you want "something" in **all** cases, but when that "something" is null you want "something else".

Comment: Let me try it out

Comment: This answer solves my question but does not solve my problem, because i did not thinked well in the solution. I really have to use nvl because i will not replace directly the null column in the scalar subquery. I'll have to get another column value to use in the where clause of my third SELECT clause. Ty anyway

Answer (score 1):

Try using coalesce:

```
select cast(...) as document_id, cast(...) as document_type_id, ...
...
, coalesce( (the first scalar subquery),
            (the second scalar subquery),
            any_column_name
          )
  end as company_id,
...
```

It will return the first non-null result.